# Pyserial, in_waiting gives empty value '0L'

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port, pyserial

currently I am struggling with serial communication to an external device using Python 2.7/ Pyserial. As an alternative I used a terminal software for data logging: [Screenshot of fomerly used Software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqaer.png).
One can see the device first gives a header line followed by cyclic updated data strings (separated lines with CR LF each)

Now trying to get the data into Python somehow does not work, cp:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM8', 38400)
```

Then

```
ser.inWaiting()
```

gives

```
0L
```

The buffer seems to be empty when accessing from python while the terminal software runs fine.

I tried setting

```
ser.setDTR(1)
ser.dsrdtr=1
```

both without success.

Further information: The device runs on a virtual port splitter. The USB cable is connected to COM3. There are two tools accessing the device using COM6 (for device configuration over HMI) and COM8 for data logging as described here.

I really appreciate any help.

Regards,
mulm

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a workaround for my problem. Since the terminal software that works with my device runs fine I use its built in http-server and then make a request using Python. Now I have to start an extra software, but in my case this is the best option available.

Used software:
http://www.umonfw.com/ucon/

Code snippet:

```
import socket

# Closing the connection after a single request prevents the buffer from filling up with outdated data.

try:
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(('xxx.xx.xx.xxx', 50080))

    val = client.recv(96)

    client.close()

except socket.error:
    print "Unable to connect to server."
    val = None
```

Not pretty but it does the job.